# how to commit virtual envinroment

Tags: python, git, github, repository, git-commit

I have a Python code with virtual env and libraries  on my local but in GitHub repository there is no virtual env/libraries.

I removed virtual environment  from git-ignore but still the libraries are not getting committed to repository and when I clone it to another system I don't have it.

What is the best practice to commit env and libraries to repository or better to install it again on each computer. If it's acceptable to commit virtual env, can you please advise how to do it.

Comment: Usually virtualenvs and installed libraries should not be committed to your repo. You can use `pip` to save a requirements file or you can manage your libraries with more advanced tools like `pipenv`. You have just to commit "lists" of packages, not the complete virtualenv

Comment: @floatingpurr thanks, do you have a sample of how to manage dependencies with 'pipenv'

Comment: The official documentation is good enough and could be your starting point https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally do it by installing through requirements and push the requirements to the repo. Eg:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Will make a list of all packages and libraries that you've installed in the virtual environment (assuming you're in the environment of course, and not transferred any from the global environment). If you push the requirements.txt file, you can create a new virtual environment as usual and install the requirements:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```